# Is there a single word for "Not Full"?

Tags: single-word-requests

As in, if there is space for 100 grubles in my zeblar, is there a single word which means the zeblar contains between 0 and 99 grubles?

I'm looking for it to fit the sentence:
"No [not full] slots have been found."

Using the hyphenated "No non-full..." sounds like a marginally confusing double negative

Comment: *Unfilled*, perhaps? *My zeblar is unfilled.*

Comment: @mick Unfilled is the best, I think. If you make it into an answer i'll accept it

Comment: Your example sentence seems to work with _free_: _No free slots have been found_. Alternatively, _available_ seems to work, in the sense that _non-available_ would mean that the slot is completely full.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Unfilled* would work:

- My zeblar is unfilled.
- No unfilled slots have been found.

> **unfilled**
>
> not filled
>
> - an unfilled bottle
> - unfilled spaces
> - a vacancy left unfilled
> - an unfilled order

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unfilled)

Answer (score 0):

Try “incomplete”, “unfinished”, or “partial”... or synonyms for these.

Comment: None of these would work in provided context because “my zeblar is incomplete” characterises zeblar itself rather than space available in it. Same with other words.